# ClassNotFoundException when trying to load classes from JAR

Tags: java

I have the following structure in my code:

[image]

Inside the bin folder, I have two packages: carFactory and bikeFactory. I've created a jar to each one of the factories directories. Then, i moved both jar to the plugins directory, on the root of my project.

In my code, when i try to load the class using:

```
          IAbstractFactory factory = (IAbstractFactory) Class.forName("carFactory.CarFactory", true, ulc)
              .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

I get the error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

UPDATE:

The code was written on Eclipse but i'm trying to execute on CMD.

[The tree under src.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzS0c.png)

Contents of classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-14">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="A:/Libs/RSyntaxTextArea/rsyntaxtextarea-3.1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: This is eclipse is it? Did you perhaps forget to REFRESH in eclipse after copying the files there??

Comment: Is the plugins directory actually in the classpath?  Can you atttach the contents of the .classpath file into the answer?

Comment: Can you show the tree under src - so we can be sure it's not a typo?

Comment: |Thanks for the help! I've updated the question.

Comment: You need to specify a classpath when running from the cmd line ... e.g `java -classpath "plugins/carFactory.jar:plugins/bikeFactory.jar:bin" Tester`.  It doesn't know anything about eclipse or its .classpath. (that was all assuming you were at the top level - above src).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr R was right. Ty for the help :).